# C warning 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void

Tags: c, warnings

I have this warning.

```
warning : 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void.
```

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I rub here!" "Well, stop doing it, then!" :-P Seriously, if a function has a return type, don't just `return;`, but return a value of the required type.

Comment: it happens when you have no return statement for a function who is returning a non-void value. you just need to use a return statement.

Comment: What's returned actually if we just use return; wouldn't the stack get corrupted?

Answer (score 17):

You have something like:

```
int function(void)
{
    return;
}
```

Add a return value, or change the return type to void.

The error message is very clear:

> warning : 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void.

A return with no value is similar to what I showed.  The message also tells you that if the function returns 'void', it would not give the warning.  But because the function is supposed to return a value but your 'return' statement didn't, you have a problem.

This is often indicative of ancient code.  In the days before the C89 standard, compilers did not necessarily support 'void'.  The accepted style was then:

```
function_not_returning_an_explicit_value(i)
char *i;
{
    ...
    if (...something...)
        return;
}
```

Technically, the function returns an `int`, but no value was expected.  This style of code elicits the warning you got - and C99 officially outlaws it, but compilers continue to accept it for reasons of backwards compatibility.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation of why this is merely treated as a warning.

Answer (score 4):

This warning also happens if you forget to add a return statement as the last statement:

```
int func(){}
```

If you don't specify the return type of a function it defaults to int not to void so these are also errors:

```
func(){}
func(){ return; }
```

If you really do not need to return a value you should declare your function as returning void:

```
void func(){}
void func(){ return; }
```

Answer (score 3):

This warning happens when you do this:

```
int t() { return; }
```

Because `t()` is declared to return an `int`, but the return statement isn't returning an `int`. The correct version is:

```
int t() { return 0; }
```

Obviously your code is more complicated, but it should be fairly easy to spot a bare `return` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

while making a new class declare a class as void
i.g.

```
void sum(int a, int b)
{
 //function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are not declaring any function with void(null) return value,

```
void examPle(){//Function block with no return type }
```

, you should always specify a valid return type you expext as the o/p. Below is the basic syntax of what you should be returning when writing your **main** block.

```
int main(){ 
return 0;
}
```

here **return 0;** means success.