# Warning 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void - What should it return?

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

How do I solve the following throwing the warning in the title?

```
struct Nodes* InsertNode(unsigned int IP, unsigned short Port)
{
    if (!IP)
       return;
    if (!Port)
       return;
    // Above is what chucks the warnings
    {
        // do stuff & conditionally
           return &List[x];
    }
    // Different conditions & stuff
    {
       return &List[Other];
    }
}
```

In other words, in the case of giving up through missing data, what should it return?  Or do I need to trawl through the entire body of code and have checks every time to see if it should be called or not?  The program functions as intended just returning at that point, if I'm to continue using it (or upgrade the OS it's running on), fixing compiler warnings seems like a good idea, they tend to turn into errors when compiler versions get bumped.

There's a clue in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2422651) which answers someone asking about the same warning, the answer doesn't give me quite enough info to proceed though, nor do the other's I've read.

Extra information: The check on the values of **IP** & **Port** are there to sanitize the content of **&List**, such cases indicate datagrams from misconfigured clients or traffic from persons with malicious intent, sad but it happens. It's invalid data we don't care about *at all*, logging it seems pointless, it shouldn't delay processing the next one, and absolutely not halt the program. Until the switch from gcc 4.9 to 6.3 I didn't see a warning. The current **return;** *appears* to simply black-hole it, but I only understand bits of the code's intent.

Comment: lying to the compiler is highly discouraged. in fact, no good can come of it. Return NULL. You'll find out right-quick if anyone is dereferencing the result in the cases you state the callers don't seem to care.

Comment: Just return NULL; and tell the caller to check the state before accessing it.

Comment: You might want to look at the code that calls this function to see if it handles `NULL` pointers. You could also just `exit()` the program with an error message instead of returning with `return;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the case of giving up through missing data,  what should it return?

As often it depends.

There are several scenarios

1. ### The function is not designed to return `NULL` as a valid value.

   Replace

   ```
   if (!IP)
     return;
   if (!Port)
     return;
   ```

   by

   ```
   if (!IP || !Port)
   {
     errno = EINVAL; /* Setting errno, allows the caller to log 
                        the failure using the perror() function. */
     return NULL;
   }
   ```

   Use it like this:

   ```
   struct Nodes * p = InsertNode (...);
   if (NULL == p)
   {
      perror("InsertNode() failed");
      /* exit or error logging/handling */
   }
   ```
2. ### `IP` and `Port` will *never* be `0` under normal operation. So if they were it would be a programming mistake.

   In those cases you probably no don't return but end the program.

   So instead of

   ```
   if (!IP)
     return;
   if (!Port)
     return;
   ```

   use

   ```
   assert((IP) && (Port));
   ```

   No specific usage necessary here as the program would simply end if the assertion isn't met.

   *Please **note** that this approach **requires extensive testing** as the test will typically be removed in a production/release build!*
3. ### The function *may* return `NULL` as valid value *and* `IP` and/or `Port` *may* be `0` under normal operation.

   Redesign the function to in one way or the other return a separate error status.

   This can generally be done in two ways:

   - #### Use the function's return value and pass back the result via a pointer being passed as parameter

     ```
     int InsertNode(unsigned int IP, unsigned short Port, struct Nodes** ppresult)
     {
       int error_state = 0;

       if (!IP || !Port || !ppresult)
       {
         errno = EINVAL; /* Setting errno, allows the caller to log 
                        the failure using the perror() function. */
         error_state = -1;
       }
       else
       {
         if (...)
         {
           *ppresult = &List[x];
         }

         ...

       }

       return error_state;
     }
     ```

     Use it like this:

     ```
     struct Nodes * p;
     if (-1 == InsertNode (..., &p))
     {
        perror("InsertNode() failed");
       /* exit or error logging/handling */
     }
     ```
   - #### Pass back the error state result via a pointer being passed as parameter

     ```
     struct Nodes * InsertNode(unsigned int IP, unsigned short Port, int * perror_state)
     {
       int error_state = 0;

       if (!IP || !Port || !perror_state)
       {
         errno = EINVAL; /* Setting errno, allows the caller to log 
                        the failure using the perror() function. */
         error_state = -1;
       }
       else
       {
         if (...)
         {
           *ppresult = &List[x];
         }

         ...

       }

       *perror_state = error_state;

       return NULL;
     }
     ```

     Use it like this:

     ```
     int result;
     struct Nodes * p = InsertNode (..., &result))
     if (-1 == result)
     {
       perror("InsertNode() failed");
       /* exit or error logging/handling */
     }
     ```

Comment: +1, but since OP claimed to not be a programmer before the edit, a viable option to getting the code to compile and run may be to simply bail out of the `InsertNode()` function with `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`, maybe printing an error message first, but without further ceremony.

Comment: @DavidBowling: "*... further ceremony.*" LOL - Doing it quick&dirty happens by itself, doesn't? ;-)

Comment: Shame it's C & not [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) _that_ I can more-or-less write in. Ultimately I suspect 3. above is the solution here, though 1 & 2 may be applicable to other functions that do a similar "naughty" `return;` probably was accepted in '05 when it was written. It'll take me ages to work through the code. Many thanks also to @David for the explanation of the changes I suspect `gcc -std=gnu90` will probably have to do in the interim.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

"Until the switch from gcc 4.9 to 6.3 I didn't see a warning." Try compiling with `gcc -std=gnu90` to compile under similar conditions to those that worked before, when you were using gcc 4.9.

### OK, I'm Listening

The reason that you see compiler warnings after changing compilers from gcc 4.9 to gcc 6.3 is that gcc 4.9 defaulted to C90 (really the gnu90 dialect of C90), but by gcc 5.5 the default was C11 (really gnu11).

The C90 Standard says in the *Constraints* section about the `return` statement that (C90 §6.6.6.4):

> A **return** statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is **void**.

But the same *Constraints* section from the C11 Standard says[C11 §6.8.6.4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.4):

> A **return** statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is **void**. *A **return** statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is **void**.*

Now, the compiler must produce a diagnostic message for any constraint violation ([§5.1.1.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.3)). No constraint was violated when your code was compiled under C90, but the change to a more recent compiler means that the code now compiles under C11, where there *is* a constraint violation, hence the warning.

One option would be to simply compile with `gcc -std=gnu90`, allowing the code to be compiled using the same dialect of C you used before, even on the more recent compilers.

But, also note that the original code may have had *undefined behavior*, since (C90 §6.6.6.4):

> If a **return** statement with an expression is executed, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

If the value returned by `InsertNode()` is used by the caller, and the `return;` statement is encountered in the function call, you have undefined behavior. The best choice would be to look at all of the calls to `InsertNode()` to see how they handle the return values. It is possible that `return;` is a typo, and that the code already handles returned null pointers, in which case changing to `return NULL;` would be all that is needed to fix the code. If the code does not already handle null pointers, [@alk has provided several options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51807170/6879826) for fixing the code.